# Why AtomicLong uses putLongVolatile to set its value?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

Considering this statement from [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> - Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile
>   (including long and double variables).

Why does `AtomicLong` uses some native method `putLongVolatile` instead of just setting its volatile `value` like `AtomicInteger` does?

Comment: Where is `putLongVolatile`?

Comment: My guess would be that the JDK uses the same code for both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms. On 32-bit platforms, long operations need to be guarded because they involve two separate 32-bit operations.

Comment: @akuzminykh https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java#L115

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8180620

Comment: The reason is that there is no reason, they are equivalent so either choice is fine.